# if: Expression Syntax cshell

Tags: shell, grep, csh

I am taking input from the user. I perform two checks; the first is to make sure that it does not contain any numbers and the second is to ensure that there are no white spaces.

```
    set test = `echo $last_name | grep "[0-9]"`
    if ($test != "") then
        echo "vBalance [Error] last_name: Employee name should only contain letters!"
        continue
    endif
    set test = `echo $last_name | grep " "` 
    if ("$test" != "") then
        echo "vBalance [Error] last_name: Employee last name must not contain spaces!"
        continue
    endif
```

The first check is performed without problems. The second check, however, I recieve "if: Expression Syntax" error.

I tried using "" around the variable : `if ("$test" != "") then`
I also removed the "" : `if ($test != "") then`

Niether one solved the problem.

Comment: The syntax seems correct; you might have a CRLF line ending problem

Comment: you fix CRLF problems by running `dos2unix myBrokenScript`. ALSO `test` is a "resevered" word in most shells, including `csh`. so get in the habit of using `myTest` or TstR` or something else. ALSO, if those don't solve it, I kind of remember that the `(,)` parens need to be separated by spaces from both inside and out chars/syntax/vars/etc. (Not certain about that) ... But try `if ( $myTest != "" ) then` ... Good luck.

Comment: Why do you want to disallow space in surnames? Leonardo da Vinci. Vincent van Gogh. Sacha Baron Cohen.

Comment: Very informative! I didn't know that Baron is part of the surname.